# How to hide some pages from users and only show it to Admin ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed the Activ Admin gem but not sure it will be of any help. I have some pages which I want to hide from being seen by anonymous and some from logged in users too. How can I do it ?

I am sure there must be ACL gems in RoR but I am not sure which is the standard and preferred way to do it ? any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Active Admin but,
assuming you already have a way of determining if a user is logged in (and you have a way to address the `current_user`), you could simply do the following:

#### in your controller (or in your sessionshelper for example)

```
def admin_users_only
  unless current_user.admin? redirect_to "wherever you want to redirect to"
end
```

#### in the same controller

```
before_filter :admin_users_only, only: [:index, :or, :any, :other]
```

(of course your user model needs an admin attribute)